# Removing the link on woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to remove the link on the product name, which redirects to product page when clicked on cart page. I tried to modify **cart.php** file but it did not work. I tried to modify these lines:

```
<td class="product-name">
<?php
    if (! $_product->is_visible())
        echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
    else
        echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title()), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

    // Meta data
    echo WC()->cart->get_item_data($cart_item);

    // Backorder notification
    if ($_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder($cart_item['quantity']))
        echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . __('Available on backorder', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
?>
</td>
```

What is the proper modification on this code to remove link on the product name?

Comment: mmm removing the `sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink()` looks like it may be something :D

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to add the following filter in your active theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink','__return_false');
```

Please note that it will remove the product link from both product title and product thumbnail from the cart page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is the correct file, I'd try to change

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

to

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s', $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Good luck.

Comment: i have tried both of the suggestions it did not work :(

Comment: cart.php seems to be correct.. try copying it to selectedtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php . Does my answer change anything at all? Add some debugging information to the file to see what's happening and take it from there.

Comment: yes the location that i placed cart.php is right too. actually i do not know what does mean adding debugging information? i did some research but i could not be able to understand.

Comment: It's when you add lines of code to output comments (anything) or variable values so that you can follow what's happening in the program.. where it goes wrong or whether a condition passes. Example: If you type `td` after `<td class="product-name">`, upload it and you can see `td` at the beginning of each product row, it means that you have the correct file and it's updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When it is necessary to modify woocommerce php file, must create a new directory called "woocommerce" in .../wp-content/themes/yourtheme/ and then put this modified php file in it.